# Javascript context menu for images

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, copy-protection

I have a website where lots of people copy images off it, which is fine.  What I do want to do, however, is help them embed it on the target website they are going to.

Ideally this would take the form where when a user right clicks the image a context menu will appear giving them easy options to embed or share the image.

What is the best way to do this?

P.s. I don't care about them hotlinking, or saving the images at all, all I want to do is provide the user with an easier way to share the images!

Comment: I hate it when people add this crap to their websites.  If you want to annoy your users to all hell then do something like this.

Comment: I don't think it makes a lot of sense to vote a question down because you don't like the implications of an implementation based on the answer. It's a perfectly reasonable question from the standpoint of software development.

Comment: It's not about preventing them from downloading it nor annoying them, most of them WANT the help so they can post the images on other websites.

Comment: P.s. Thanks Pointy - It is impossible for you to know the context for the application for this code.  Most of my users don't know that much about computers so any help I give them is better for them.  What I'm trying to do is give a better user experience and reduce support emails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can prevent the common user from bothering, but the fact is the URL is sent to the browser to download. So at the very least I could view the source and figure it out.

If you really want to try to annoy the user, though, you can attach an `oncontextmenu` event which will capture the right-click in some browsers.

**edit**:

In response to your comment..

Since you're using jQuery, you can use [this plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/05/jquery-right-click-plugin/) to detect right clicks. It has been tested on most browsers.

You can then use something like [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) to display the modal box you want to show the user..

```
$('img').rightClick(function (e) {
    $.modal(...);
});
```

Comment: Users generally like to copy off the images so I figured it'd be a nice way for me to help them by providing easy access to embed codes etc

Answer (score 7):

Don't send the image to their browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually render HTML as embedded mime data in all major browsers except for IE:

http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Data_URIs_and_Inline_Images

Another weird, but workable solution is to convert the image to CSS:

http://elliottback.com/wp/convert-image-to-css/

Neither is really that great a solution, but it highlights the fact that you need to be willing to lose an image by just putting on the web.

Even if you use a plug-in, people can just do a screen capture.